# How do I parse XML with duplicate nodes?

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

Here is my XML file. There are three `author` nodes in there:

```
<bookstore>    
  <book category="web">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
  </book>    
</bookstore>
```

When I use `var author = $(this).find('author');`, `author` holds all the authors in one string. I want to get it as an array. Is there any way to do it?

```
var author = $(this).find('author').toArray();
```

returns array with 0 length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find('author')` will return you back a jQuery object which holds a collection of nodes. As such you can just loop over them using `each()`:

```
var authors = $(this).find('author');
authors.each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

If you specifically want an array of all the values, then you can use `map()`:

```
var authors = $(this).find('author').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
```